# Nesting a textview and an Imagebutton in a FrameLayout which is nested in a table row

Tags: java, android, nested, tablelayout

Hi all hope i do a better job explaining what i need below.. thanks in advance for your help..

**What im trying to do:** Im trying to dynamically create a table of image buttons. When each image button is clicked, a counter badge/bubble (like the update icon u see on apps when there is an update in iphones). This badge should show one the top left corner of the image button.

**My logic:** To do that i thought that i need to create a tablerow, then in that tablerow put a FrameLayout, and in that FrameLayout but in the Image button and a text view that will display the badge image. Reason i use a FrameLayout is because i need to have the TextView overlap the Imagebutton to get the effect i want...

**The Problem:** I wrote the code below and it runs with no errors but no counter badge!! It seems like the application ignores the badge and only creates the image buttons for me.... Need help to make it work

HELP !!!

```
ContentView(R.layout.activitymenu);
TableLayout table =(TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.MenuButtonTable);


for (int row=0; row<NUM_Array_Rows;row++) {
//Set new Row in Table
TableRow tableRow = new TableRow(this);
tableRow.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 0.1F));
table.addView(tableRow);


for (int col = 0; col < NUM_Array_Clns; col++) {

int x, y;
final int FINAL_COL = col;
final int FINAL_ROW = row;
final int FINAL_BtnCounter = BtnCounter;
final String SW_NAME;
float w;


final ImageButton ImButton = new ImageButton(this);
final FrameLayout FrmLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
final TextView txtView = new TextView(this);


FrameLayout.LayoutParams layout1 =
new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams. WRAP_CONTENT,FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
FrmLayout.setLayoutParams(layout1);

ViewGroup.LayoutParams layout2 =
new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP _CONTENT,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

txtView.setLayoutParams(layout2);
txtView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.RIGHT);
txtView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.badge);
txtView.setText("2");
FrmLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_laun cher);


ImButton.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(BtnWidth, BtnHight,0.1F));
Resources res = getResources();

SW_NAME = MenuArray[col][1]; //SW NAme
temp = MenuArray[col][3];
int id = res.getIdentifier(temp, "drawable", MenuActivity.this.getPackageName());
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.sw03);
ImButton.setBackground(drawable);
BtnCounter = BtnCounter + 1;
ImButtonArray[row][col] = BtnCounter; // just storing button positions in this array

ImButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
int SW_ID;
SW_ID = BtnCounter;
onPrepareOptionsMenu(FINAL_ROW, FINAL_COL);
}
});

tableRow.addView(FrmLayout);

tableRow.addView(ImButton);

FrmLayout.addView(txtView);
```

Comment: A crash without stacktrace is generally not very helpful. Also it crashes *mostly* (??) on `setContentView()` - how does that work? Do you consistently get the same exception, or others too? Furthermore - not really to the point perhaps - I don't really follow your line of thought when 'realising' the view hierarchy. Could you supply an image illustrating what you're attempting to accomplish? Finally, not sure what the size of `NUM_Array_Rows` is, but consider using a `ListView` in stead of a `TableLayout`.

Comment: Hi MH. Im new at this so let me try to help you help me :).. in my code whenever i comment out the lines "setContentView" and "FrmLayout.AddView()" the code runs fine, but without the effect i want. To describe what i want to happen... this part of the app does the following:

Comment: 1.on load the page reads from an array a given menu (ideally the array has the name , price and image of the item).2. then in a table layout each menu item image is displayed on an image button on the table(max of 4 imagebuttons per row).3.When an image button is clicked a badge counter or bubble counter will then show on the top right corner of the respective image button indicating the number of times clicked (a red circle with a number inside,like app updates on iphones). Num_ArrayRows will not be more than 50 items. i would love to the stack and an image ill.. please tell me how? @peter